# Google Sheets =Query Function to Sort and not read formulated cells

Tags: jquery, sql, sorting, google-sheets, google-query-language

I am looking to sort this data by Col1 and I have try so many ways and keep getting an error. Basically I am pulling data from all these tabs and giving me values based off the value in the dropdown list in D2. I also have formulas in the other cells where I am pulling data and I do not wanted it to read those cells unless a value is present. I tried one formula but it was spacing the query data every 1000 rows apart.

```
=QUERY({SHEET1!A:K;SHEET2!A:K;SHEET3!A:K;SHEET4!A:K;SHEET5!A:K;SHEET6!A:K;SHEET7!A:K;SHEET8!A:K;SHEET9!A:K}, "where Col4 ="""&D2&"""",1)
```

Comment: whats the content of D2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({SHEET1!A:K; SHEET2!A:K; SHEET3!A:K;
        SHEET4!A:K; SHEET5!A:K; SHEET6!A:K;
        SHEET7!A:K; SHEET8!A:K; SHEET9!A:K}, 
 "where Col1 is not null 
    and Col4 ="""&D2&"""
  order by Col1", 1)
```